# Running local GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have followed these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/quickstart

I had to manually associate the bundled python with .py files. When I run:

`dev_appserver.py --port 8087 helloworld/`

I get **"too few parameters"** errors?

Googling has hinted at having to explicitly state the PHP binary, etc...but the docs linked above are very clear this is not required for Windows (7) as GAE comes with a bundled PHP environment.

What am I missing? What happened to the GUI launcher - that worked nicely for me :)

`C:\Users\alex.DOMAIN\Desktop\temp>dev_appserver.py "temp\helloworld\"
usage: dev_appserver.py [-h] [-A APP_ID] [--host HOST] [--port PORT]
                        [--admin_host ADMIN_HOST] [--admin_port ADMIN_PORT]
                        [--auth_domain AUTH_DOMAIN] [--storage_path PATH]
                        [--log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}]
                        [--max_module_instances MAX_MODULE_INSTANCES]
                        [--use_mtime_file_watcher [USE_MTIME_FILE_WATCHER]]
                        [--threadsafe_override THREADSAFE_OVERRIDE]
                        [--php_executable_path PATH]
                        [--php_remote_debugging [PHP_REMOTE_DEBUGGING]]
                        [--php_gae_extension_path PATH]
                        [--php_xdebug_extension_path PATH]
                        [--appidentity_email_address APPIDENTITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
                        [--appidentity_private_key_path APPIDENTITY_PRIVATE_KEY_
PATH]
                        [--python_startup_script PYTHON_STARTUP_SCRIPT]
                        [--python_startup_args PYTHON_STARTUP_ARGS]
                        [--jvm_flag JVM_FLAG]
                        [--custom_entrypoint CUSTOM_ENTRYPOINT]
                        [--runtime RUNTIME] [--blobstore_path BLOBSTORE_PATH]
                        [--mysql_host MYSQL_HOST] [--mysql_port MYSQL_PORT]
                        [--mysql_user MYSQL_USER]
                        [--mysql_password MYSQL_PASSWORD]
                        [--mysql_socket MYSQL_SOCKET]
                        [--datastore_path DATASTORE_PATH]
                        [--clear_datastore [CLEAR_DATASTORE]]
                        [--datastore_consistency_policy {consistent,random,time}
]
                        [--require_indexes [REQUIRE_INDEXES]]
                        [--auto_id_policy {sequential,scattered}]
                        [--logs_path LOGS_PATH]
                        [--show_mail_body [SHOW_MAIL_BODY]]
                        [--enable_sendmail [ENABLE_SENDMAIL]]
                        [--smtp_host SMTP_HOST] [--smtp_port SMTP_PORT]
                        [--smtp_user SMTP_USER]
                        [--smtp_password SMTP_PASSWORD]
                        [--smtp_allow_tls [SMTP_ALLOW_TLS]]
                        [--prospective_search_path PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_PATH]
                        [--clear_prospective_search [CLEAR_PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH]]
                        [--search_indexes_path SEARCH_INDEXES_PATH]
                        [--clear_search_indexes [CLEAR_SEARCH_INDEXES]]
                        [--enable_task_running [ENABLE_TASK_RUNNING]]
                        [--allow_skipped_files [ALLOW_SKIPPED_FILES]]
                        [--api_port API_PORT]
                        [--automatic_restart [AUTOMATIC_RESTART]]
                        [--dev_appserver_log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,
error}]
                        [--skip_sdk_update_check [SKIP_SDK_UPDATE_CHECK]]
                        [--default_gcs_bucket_name DEFAULT_GCS_BUCKET_NAME]
                        yaml_path [yaml_path ...]
dev_appserver.py: error: too few arguments`

here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635651/google-app-engine-php-on-windows seems to defy what Google suggests about Windows having a bundled PHP version. I have tried this and nothing worked?

Comment: You should show the actual, complete, error message.

Comment: That pretty much is the error - but I've added the whole command and results above

Comment: Almost certainly your association of .py files with Python is incorrectly set up, so it is not passing on the arguments when you run the script. I don't know enough about Windows file associations to say how to fix it, although you can probably run it explicitly with "C:\path\to\python.exe dev_appserver.py temp\helloworld\".

Comment: You are already in the `temp` directory.  Why `temp/helloworld/`?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `dev_appserver.py --port=8087 helloworld/`

EDIT: Make sure that `helloworld/` exists in your current directory, and that it contains a valid app.yaml

Comment: With port and without forward slashes back slashes, with and without...I have tried so many combinations and still no luck...

Comment: You need to make sure that `helloworld` exists in your current directory, and that it contains a valid `app.yaml`

Comment: OK that I wasn't doing - so I backed up one directory and called: dev_appserver.py temp/ it has a valid app.yaml and helloworld.php

Answer (score 0):

This has many possible problems and solutions, and has been asked before.  Check out:

[GAE Python : dev_appserver.py: error: too few arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805871/gae-python-dev-appserver-py-error-too-few-arguments)

[Starting Google App Engine Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526676/starting-google-app-engine-web-server)

[Google App Engine PHP on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635651/google-app-engine-php-on-windows)

https://github.com/wri/api-hello-world/issues/1